# Modeling data in Hive tables in Caravel

Tags: hadoop, hive, druid

I am curious if there is a way to model the data from Hive tables in Caravel.

Similar to how caravel can connect to a Druid cluster and display a UI on the data in Druid, is there a way to model the data in Hive in Caravel using JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, take a look into the https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive.
You can specify the sql alchemy connection string and connect to the Hive.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I would use this to read data from hive into Druid?

Comment: Ah, for that your would need to write the export pipeline, that is outside of the caravel scope.

Comment: Is export pipeline is defined somewhere or is it my custom code to move data from Hive into Druid?